# Automatic keyboard layout detection on Window 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, auto-detect

I wonder if there is (and where to find it) a tool for Windows 7 similar to the one built-in in Mac OS X, that detects your keyboard layout by pressing a couple of keys in your keyboard.

The automatic keyboard layout detection tool is launched while in the process of installing the Mac OS X system, when the installer detects a keyboard other than the one built-in in the hardware, for what matters.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly detected using your keyboard, it seems that Windows can make an assumption based on location, and [can also pass that information to a remote desktop if using RDP](http://www.michelstevelmans.com/multiple-languages-regional-options-keyboard-layouts-citrix-appsense/).

Additionally, during setup (at least for Win7 and up, not sure about Vista), [you are asked to specify your keyboard format](http://www.bleepstatic.com/tutorials/windows-7/recovery-command-prompt/setup-language-options.jpg).

Comment: Yes, I saw the options to enter the keyboard format, but wasn't sure about what to select, and there wasn't a text box where to try some keys to see if the selection was right.